# How do i validate with index of more than 50?

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a car list of index size of 49 and when i submit the form the validation (Laravel Validator) it works but when i add another car to the list so the index size is 50 now the validation fails at the last index. Any idea how can i solve it?

Comment: Please show some code.. Without it helping you would be almost impossible.

Comment: its fixed. its because of the php.ini default config which allows a certain limit to be process only.